# Story about a complex solution vs letting it fail

Tags: history

I'm looking for a reference. It's a story about a team that solved a problem in a pretty complex way and the other simply let it fail, than the client would crash (or something like that) and it wouldn't be a problem for it to restart.

I'm pretty sure I've read it somewhere in the book [The Art of Unix Programming](http://catb.org/%7Eesr/writings/taoup/html/), but I can't find it.

Comment: Related over at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393197/erlangs-let-it-crash-philosophy-applicable-elsewhere

Comment: Why downvotes? The question is about a specific known illustration of some design principles of Unix, which should be on-topic here and can be covered by the [tag:history] tag.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it, the original story is in ["The Rise of Worse is Better" by Richard P. Gabriel](https://dreamsongs.com/RiseOfWorseIsBetter.html) and I also read about it in [The Art of Unix Programming](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/writings/taoup/html/ch13s01.html). In summary the story is:

> Two famous people, one from MIT and another from Berkeley (but working on Unix) once met to discuss operating system issues. The person from MIT was interested in how Unix solved the PC loser-ing problem, that it's basically about how system calls that do long operations handle interrupts they cannot hold or mask. The MIT guy did not see any code that handled this case and asked the New Jersey guy how the problem was handled. The New Jersey guy said that the Unix folks were aware of the problem, but the solution was for the system routine to always finish, but sometimes an error code would be returned that signaled that the system routine had failed to complete its action. A correct user program, then, had to check the error code to determine whether to simply try the system routine again. The MIT guy did not like this solution because it was not the “right” thing. The New Jersey guy said that the Unix solution was right because the design philosophy of Unix was simplicity and that the right thing was too complex. Besides, programmers could easily insert this extra test and loop. The MIT guy pointed out that the implementation was simple but the interface to the functionality was complex. The New Jersey guy said that the right tradeoff has been selected in Unix -- namely, implementation simplicity was more important than interface simplicity.